# Face Recognition opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to implement the Face Recognition using opencv and python.
And instead of recognizing face from a webcam i want to recognize faces from a video.
I used this code to recognize from a webcam and it works. But when l changed  the code to read from a video I get an error.

```
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
time.sleep(2)

while True:
    (_, im) = webcam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

webcam = cv2.VideoCapture('man.avi')
time.sleep(2)

while True:
    (_, im) = webcam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

To read from a video, i used:

```
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture('man.avi')
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-09b5782a88bc> in <module>()
     38 while True:
     39     (_, im) = webcam.read()
---> 40     gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     41 
     42     faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    Error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:3739: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor
```

Any suggestion on solving that?

Comment: Mind the note in the [documentation](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#playing-video-from-file): "*Make sure proper versions of ffmpeg or gstreamer is installed. Sometimes, it is a headache to work with Video Capture mostly due to wrong installation of ffmpeg/gstreamer.*"

Comment: Are you sure you are giving the correct overload? Since you used 0, which is an integer, in the working code.

Comment: try full path to you video like "C:/mydata/man.avi" or  "/home/user/myvideos/man.avi" just to be sure you got no unexpected workin directory...

Comment: It was a codec problem (FFmpeg). Now it works

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the when

```
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture('man.avi')
```

the following

```
while True:
    (_, im) = webcam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

will read until, even pass, the end of video. There, `im` is an empty `np.array` and thus, `cvtColor` will fail and give the error you saw. Check this condition will eliminate the error, for example

```
while True:
    (ret, im) = webcam.read()

    # end of video, break the loop
    if not ret:
        break

    # valid frame
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```